# When I should use windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds attribute?

Tags: android

I read some articles about android fitsSystemWindows attribute and customized behavior in some widgets for that (i.e. navigation drawer) and there is no questions. But from documentation I can't really understand the difference between windowTranslucentStatus and windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds. Can someone please explain when each of this attribute should/shouldn't be used?

I suppose that I need to use windowTranslucentStatus + fitsSystemWindows and windowTranslucentNavigation + clipToPadding, but what is windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds for?

Answer (score 14):

When `android:windowTranslucentStatus` is set to `true` the window requests a transparent status bar

[WindowTranslucentStatus documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowTranslucentStatus)

`android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` set to `true` results that everything may be drawn under status bar on API level 21 and above.